# How to get the referenced table and column names for a constraint from the information schema in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

In mysql, I can run the following query which would give me the tables and columns used in a foreign relationship:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME as name,
       TABLE_NAME as parent_table,
       COLUMN_NAME as parent_column,
       REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME as referenced_table, 
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME as referenced_column
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
where table_schema = 'public'
 and REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME is not null
```

How do I get the equivalent information in postgresql? The key_column_usage table in postgres doesn't seem to have the referenced table and column names.

Comment: The `information_schema` should work the same in all SQL standard compliant databases. Did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you :?

```
SELECT    *
    FROM      information_schema.columns
    WHERE     column_name like '%NAME%'
    AND       table_name not like '%NAME%'
```